# How to get the category id of the product being ordered on success.phtml file in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to send custom email on order completion. So I am writing the email logic in the success.phtml file. This email will be based on the condition of the category id.

If the product being ordered is from the category1 then email will send to email-address1 and if the product being ordered is from the category2 then email will send to email-address2.

So how will I get the category id of the product being ordered in the success.phtml file?

Comment: This is not possible without extensive work. Please see my answer to your related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309247/magento-sales-order-place-after-observer-not-working/8312319#8312319

Answer (score 0):

Few tips

- don't ever write logic to template files
- it will be smarter to write this logic in to observer instead

getting the ordered items id-s is the same no matter where your code is located what matters is that you need to have access to quote or order object

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    //$item->getId();
}

foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    //$item->getId();
}
```

Comment: so then where should I write the email logic? As I want to send email to a specific email address if a product of a specific category is ordered? I am new to magento. Please help me.

Comment: as i said "observer" so make your extension add event observer to config.xml and write it in some model

Comment: I have created event observer but it is not working. Here is my post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309247/magento-sales-order-place-after-observer-not-working